# Duplicate R function and alter it

Tags: r, r-caret

Is it possible to duplicate a function in R and change the default values of a parameter in the duplicated function? For instance,

```
myFunc <- function(param1 = 1) {
  return(1+param1)
}

# Duplicate function and alter param1
myFunc2 <- some way to duplicate myFunc and alter param1=1 to param1=2
```

Background: I use [rfe](https://topepo.github.io/caret/recursive-feature-elimination.html) from the caret package for feature selection. I use rfFuncs as function, but I want to replace the default `selectSize` function with the `pickSizeTolerance` function with a higher tolerance value (2 or 3) than the default one (1.5). Here is an example

```
# Create dummy data
trainData <- data.frame(a=runif(100), b=runif(100), c=runif(100), d=runif(100), e=runif(100), f=runif(100), g=runif(100), h=runif(100),i=runif(100),j=runif(100))
trainData$label <- factor(c(rep("Class A", 50), rep("Class B", 50)))

rfFuncs$selectSize <- pickSizeTolerance
ctrlRF <- rfeControl(functions = rfFuncs,
                     method = "cv",
                     number = 5,
                     verbose = F
                     )

# Do feature selection
rfProfile <- rfe(subset(trainData, select=-c(label)),
                 trainData[, "label"],
                 rfeControl = ctrlRF,
                 sizes = 1:10,
                 metric = "Accuracy"
                 )
```

Comment: `myPickSizeTolerance = function(..., tol = 3) pickSizeTolerance(..., tol = tol)`

Comment: Awesome @Gregor .. soo simple. Don't know why I did not think of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Gregor, here's my solution. He provided the answer in his comment.

```
myPickSizeTolerance <- function(x, metric, tol=2, maximize) {
  return(caret::pickSizeTolerance(x, metric, tol, maximize))
}
rfFuncs$selectSize <- myPickSizeTolerance
```

Answer (score 0):

If the function is the one you wrote down, you don't need to duplicate it because param1 is a variable that you can define when you call the function. All you have to do is run `myFunc(param1=2)`

Comment: Yes true. Maybe my first example was a bit misleading. I want to use `pickSizeTolerance` with another tolerance value. However, this function is part of the caret package and therefore already defined.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the OP literally, a way to copy a function but change the default arguments could be something like this:

```
copyfun <- function(f, ...){
  l <- pairlist(...)
  a <- formals(f)
  n <- names(l)[names(l) %in% names(a)]
  a[n] <- l[n]
  formals(f) <- a
  f
}
```

The resulting function will be identical to the original function, except for the default arguments. One can change all or some of the arguments:

```
> copyfun(myFunc, param1=2)
function (param1 = 2) 
{
    return(1 + param1)
}


dummy <- function(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4) paste(a,b,c,d)
> copyfun(dummy, b=100)
function (a = 1, b = 100, c = 3, d = 4) 
paste(a, b, c, d)
> copyfun(dummy, b=100, c=NULL)()
[1] "1 100  4"
```

And you can still supply your own arguments instead of the default ones:

```
> copyfun(dummy, b=100, c=NULL)(a=101, c="C")
[1] "101 100 C 4"
```